# download pdf file is corrupt with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have found this code or similar code in different websites, in my application, no error is thrown, but the PDF file downloaded, when opened the file is corrupt, and its only 5KB

the url of the file is:

"https://optionline-api-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pla592d774e504e8.pdf"

The code I use to download is:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("api/[controller]/UploadFileToAzureStorage")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile([FromBody]PDF urlPdf)
        {
            string localFilePath = await CreateTemporaryFile(urlPdf.urlPDF);

            // Create storage account
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageAccount);

            // Create a blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Get a reference to a container named "mycontainer."
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(UploaderStorage.Container);

            // Get a reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with the contents of a local file
            // named "myfile".
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
            {
                await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }

            return Ok();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates temporary file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="urlPdf">PDF URL</param>
        /// <returns>Returns path of the new file</returns>
        private async Task<string> CreateTemporaryFile(string urlPdf)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(urlPdf);
            string filename = default(string);

            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);


            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlPdf, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    string fileToWriteTo = @"\\pc030\TemporaryPDF\"+filename;
                    using (Stream streamToWriteTo = System.IO.File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
                    }
                }
            }

            return   await Task.FromResult(@"\\pc030\TemporaryPDF\" + filename);

        }
```

Comment: Could you try it without specifying `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`? To me that looks like it would only download headers and ignore the response body.

Comment: await Task.FromResult( whatever ) can be replaced by whatever. It is obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should think about a decoupled design which will make your applications much more maintainable and testable.

```
interface IStreamLoader
{
    Task<Stream> GetStreamAsync( Uri uri );
}

interface IStreamRepository
{
    Task<Stream> GetAsync( string id );
    Task PutAsync( string id, Stream stream );
    Task DeleteAsync( string id );
}

public class MyController
{
    private readonly IStreamLoader _streamLoader;
    private readonly IStreamRepository _streamRepository;

    public MyController( IStreamLoader streamLoader, IStreamRepository streamRepository )
    {
        _streamLoader = streamLoader;
        _streamRepository = streamRepository;
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]/UploadFileToAzureStorage")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile([FromBody]PDF urlPdf)
    {
        Uri pdfUri = new Uri( urlPDF.urlPDF );
        using ( var pdfStream = await _streamLoader.GetStreamAsync( pdfUri ) )
        {
            await _streamRepository.PutAsync( "myblob", pdfStream );
        }
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Pretty clean, isn't it? We do not care anymore about a filename, because we only want to have a stream.

Now an `IStreamLoader` implementation with a nice feature: When we close/dispose the stream the related file will be deleted. That keeps the temporary directory clean.

```
class StreamLoader : IStreamLoader
{
    private readonly string _tempPath;

    public StreamLoader()
    {

    }

    public StreamLoader( string tempPath )
    {
        _tempPath = tempPath;
    }

    private string GetTempFileName()
    {
        string filename;
        if ( _tempPath == null )
        {
            filename = Path.GetTempFileName();
        }
        else
        {
            filename = Path.Combine( _tempPath, Guid.NewGuid().ToString() );
            using ( File.Create( filename ) )
            { }
        }
        return filename;
    }

    public async Task<Stream> GetStreamAsync( Uri uri )
    {
        Stream result;
        using ( var client = new HttpClient() )
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync( uri ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var filename = GetTempFileName();

            using ( var stream = File.OpenWrite( filename ) )
            {
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync( stream );
            }
            result = new FileStream( 
                path: filename, 
                mode: FileMode.Open, 
                access: FileAccess.Read, 
                share: FileShare.None,
                bufferSize: 4096, 
                options: FileOptions.DeleteOnClose );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

At last we need an `IStreamRepository` implementation for Azure:

```
class AzureStreamRepository : IStreamRepository
{
    private readonly CloudStorageAccount _storageAccount;
    private readonly string _containerName;

    public AzureStreamRepository( string connectionString, string containerName )
    {
        _storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse( connectionString );
        _containerName = containerName;
    }

    public async Task DeleteAsync( string id )
    {
        var blockBlob = GetBlockBlob( id );
        await blockBlob.DeleteAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Stream> GetAsync( string id )
    {
        var blockBlob = GetBlockBlob( id );
        Stream result = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            await blockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync( result );
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            result.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        result.Seek( 0, SeekOrigin.Begin );
        return result;
    }

    public async Task PutAsync( string id, Stream stream )
    {
        var blockBlob = GetBlockBlob( id );
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync( stream );
    }

    private Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlob( string id )
    {
        var client = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference( _containerName );
        return container.GetBlockBlobReference( id );
    }

}
```

You should use DI to inject the instances to the controller.

For just a quick test without DI add this constructor to the controller (`StorageAccount` looks like a `const` or `static string` property of your controller)

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController() : this( 
        new StreamLoader( @"\\pc030\TemporaryPDF\" ),
        new AzureStreamRepository( StorageAccount, UploaderStorage.Container ) )
    {}
}
```